# asp.net mvc trying to use session but controllercontext is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

i am trying to store an object in session..

in one controller, i create the object and put it in session.

```
MyObject _o = new MyObject();
Session["MyObject"] = _o;
MyObject _oo = (MyObject)Session["MyObject"]; // added for testing purposes, is not null
```

i can retrieve the object from session just fine from within same controller.

then i redirect to an action method on another controller, and in a base controller i try to access ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session and it is always null.

```
if(_obj == null)
{
    _obj = (MyObject)Session["MyObject"]; // always null
}
```

any ideas why?

thanks :-)

Comment: Wait, is MyObject an object or a type?  It's used as an object the first time, but using it as a cast type the second time.

Comment: i just changed object name to clear things up, thanks

Comment: Not enough info in your question. From what you describe it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

When access Session object?

HttpContext initialized after Controller.Initialize().